# Primefaces CommandButton does not fire actionListener method inside p:columns header facet

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

I would like to fire an actionListener from a p:commandButton inside a column header as follows:

```
<h:form id="foos">
    <p:messages id="mess" />

    <p:columns var="foo" value="#{fooBean.foos}">
        <f:facet name="header">#{foo.name} 
            <p:commandButton icon="ui-icon-trash" actionListener="#{fooBean.test()}" update=":foos" process="@this" />
        </f:facet>

        <h:outputText value="foobar" />

    </p:columns>
</h:form>
```

No matter what I try, the actionListener method never is fired.  If I move the commandButton outside of the facet it works, so I assume there is something awry with the facet component in conjunction with the commandButton.

No messages are displayed so it appears that validation is not failing.

This is under Primefaces 3.5

Comment: Are you sure that your `<p:commandButton>` is inside a single `<h:form>`?

Comment: I don't think you can wrap `html` component inside `f:facet` cause it's only to specify type like header or footer

Comment: Be aware of what `immediate="true"` means.

Comment: I don't know if you need it, but you can put `ajax="false"` to call your method.

Comment: Yes it is in a single h:form (which i omitted for brevity).  I cannot see which of the points in the linked answer is actually relevant.  Is it because the commandButton is in a f:facet?

Comment: I wish this hadn't been marked as duplicate, because it isn't a duplicate, it's a PrimeFaces bug. See my answer here: [p:commandButton action and f:setpropertyactionlistener not invoked in p:columngroup](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17838434/).

Comment: Thank you so much @patstuart - I tried everything in BalusC's post to no avail.

Comment: @patstuart Can you possibly vote to reopen in so I can link to the bug in an answer?

Comment: My reputation is not high enough. Sorry. :(

Answer (score 0):

if no ActionEvent parameter for your test method then use action

```
 .....icon="ui-icon-trash" action="#{fooBean.test}" ...
```